# How to Define GA4 Segment Based On A Custom Event

Tags: google-analytics-4

I'm tracking events in javascript like this:

```
gtag('event', cat, {
    'action': action 
});
```

Both seem to be coming through appropriately in real-time event tracking. How can I create a segment of users/sessions that have had an event with cat = X and action = Y?